# Morphisms to a disjoint union of copies of $S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a scheme and let $H$ be a set.
Let $G = \coprod_{h \in H} S_h$ where $S_h = S$.
Let $\phi : T \longrightarrow S$ be a $S$-scheme.
I try to prove that
    $$ \mathrm{Hom}_S(T, G) \simeq H^{\pi_0(T)}, $$
where $\pi_0(T)$ is the set of connected components of $T$.
Assume that $T$ is connected. Let $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_S(T, G)$.
Since $T$ is connected, there exists $h \in H$ such that $f = \alpha_{h} \circ \phi$ where $\alpha_{h} : S_{h} \longrightarrow G$ is the canonical morphism.
So, we have an isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_S(T, G) \simeq H^{\pi_{0(T)}}$.

For general $T$, let $(T_{i})_i$ be the family of connected components of $T$.
Let $(h_{i})_{i} \in H^{\pi_0(T)}$.
We have a family $(\alpha_{h_{i}} \circ \phi_{i})_{i}$ of morphisms of $T_{i}$ in $G$ (where $\phi_{i}$ denotes the structural morphism of $T_{i}$).
How can we deduce from this an element of $\mathrm{Hom}_S(T, G)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T_i$ be the connected components of $T$, and let $(h_i)_i$ be an element in $H^{\pi_0(T)}$. We define a morphism $f: T\to G$ so that the restriction of $f$ to $T_i$ is the composite of the structure morphism $T \to S$ and the inclusion of $S$ in $G$ by considering $S$ as the $h_i$ copy in $G: S = S_{h_i} \to G$.

One can also use the axioms of sheaves to reduce general $T$ to object in a covering of $T$. So once you can know how to deal with connected $T$, the general case follows immediately.